# Adding Additional Libraries With Swift Package Manager

Tags: swift-package-manager

I recently installed Firebase with Swift Package Manager. When installing it I was asked to select the libraries I wanted to include.

[image]

Shortly after adding a couple of these libraries I wanted to add another one. The only way I could figure out how to add a new one was to remove the full Firebase package and reinstall it with the additional package I needed. Is there a way to simply add another package without first completely removing the Firebase package?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

No need to remove the whole library.
Go to the **Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content** section of your application target and tap add button, you'll find all available products.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Well that wasn't very obvious  Thank you!